# How to download some byte of file?

Tags: c#, download

I'm working on program who have a database in server
This file have header(first 512 byte) that contain version of database.
I need to first step to check the version of database and if it's new download complete file
How can do this ?

```
string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filepath"];
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), "my.db");
```

and other question is when the have not connected to net i received download completed message !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by the WebClient.OpenRead method which returns an asbtract stream instance. By this one you can read the first 512 bytes, and then the residual data if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below...

```
            WebClient req = new WebClient();
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.Clear();
            response.ClearContent();
            response.ClearHeaders();
            response.Buffer = true;

            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1) + "\"");
            byte[] data = req.DownloadData(url);
            response.BinaryWrite(data);
```